# la fecha se muestra con un día menos mediante Angular

Tags: angular, spring, date

Cuando guardo un registro, la fecha se guarda en la bd sin problemas pero me muestra con un día menos en el tabla de listado de usuario en el frontend (con angular), ya intente hacer varias cosas y sigo con ese problema.
Estoy trabajando con spring Boot y Angular

```
Cliente.java

@NotNull(message = "no puede estar vacio")
@Column(name="create_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, locale = "es_PE", timezone = "America/Lima")
private Date createAt;
private Date createAt;
```

Luego intente:

```
Cliente.java

@NotNull(message = "no puede estar vacio")
@Column(name="create_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createAt;

application.properties

spring.jackson.time-zone=America/Lima
spring.jackson.locale=es_PE
```

Por el lado de Angular.

```
Formulario.component.html

<div class="form-group row">
      <!--col-sm-2, del total de 12 columnas que exite va ocupar 2-->
      <label for="createAt" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Fecha</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="cliente.createAt" name="createAt">

      </div>
  </div>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, tal vez hay alguna configuracion con respecto al TimeZone y locale, que tengan que coincidir en Spring Boot y Angular.
O alguna configuración en mi Laptop windows10.
La verdad no se como solucionar ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te pueda servir lo siguiente:
Debes instalar la libreria 'moment'

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

public date: any;

const createdAtCovert = moment(cliente.createAt, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(1, 'days');
this.date = createdAtCovert.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola, como podría meter todos todos los datos de LOS clientes en un array?      {id: this.clientes[i].id, nombre:this.clientes[i].nombre,       apellido:this.clientes[i].apellido,email:this.clientes[i].email, createAt: this.date}               estoy realizandolo dentro del .suscribe()    en el cliente.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Cambialo de

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

a

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

y te funcionará.
Yo tambien tuve el mismo problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es javascript. Bueno ni es un problema como tal.

Lo que sucede es que cuando tú creas una fecha en js

```
'1991/06/06' !== '06/06/1991'
```

Por el formato cambia, cuando pones el año al final a la fecha se le resta un día, con la hora cero

```
1991/06/05:00:00:00
```

Lo que en teoría vendría siendo 6 de junio, porque el último minuto del 5 de junio es 11:59:59

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar `DatePipe` con la siguiente zona horaria:

```
{{ varFecha | date: "dd/MM/yy h:mm a":"GMT+0" }}
```

Answer (score -2):

¿No funcionaría básicamente añadiendo a la variable un +1?, o sea:

```
Día = (Variable + 1)
```

Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: añadiendole 1 a que variable? por favor, mira por favor [answer]